# How can I expand this expression to the return types of callables?

Tags: c++, parameter-expansion, fold-expression

Why can't I expand the parameter types?

```
auto lambda = []() { return 'c'; };

template <typename ... Ts>
struct MyClass
{

};

template <typename ... Ts>
void createMyClass(Ts&& ... ts)
{
    /* SUPPOSED TO CREATE MY CLASS WITH THE RETURN VALUES OF THE CALLABLES */
    MyClass< (decltype(std::declval<Ts>()()), ...)> d;

}


int main()
{
    createMyClass(lambda, lambda);

    
    return 0;
}
```

`decltype(std::declval<Ts>()())` is supposed to get the type of the return value from a call to `Ts`. Then I try to expand that by doing , ... after it, and wrapping it in parentheses, which is a fold expression. The equivalent to what I'm looking for is essentially `MyClass<return_type1, return_type2, return_type_n>`.

```
"syntax error: ',' was unexpected here
```

and

```
syntax error: unexpected token '...' following 'statement'
```

Comment: You can't put parens here. MyClass<(int, int)> doesn't work

Answer (score 5):

Should be

```
MyClass<decltype(std::declval<Ts>()())...>
```

or

```
MyClass<decltype(ts())...>
```

`(Es, ...)` would be a [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) (with expression not type, so `Es` instead of `Ts`) using the comma operator.

Comment: Why doesn't the fold expression work? I thought the parentheses were needed around the fold expression. And it's possible to use fold expression with decltype in this case? If I remove the outer parentheses is it still seen as a fold expression? It doesn't work.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Why doesn't my version (a fold expression over the comma operator) work?

Comment: @Zebrafish I wish I knew the correct terminology for this. What you have tried to supply as a template parameters is `(T1, T2, ..., Tx)`. Compare `MyClass<int, int, int>` and `MyClass<(int, int, int)>`. You could `declval` the `int`s to make it compile and get `MyClass<decltype(int{}, int{}, int{})>` - but that'd only give you the type of the last parameter.

Answer (score 2):

No parentheses are needed, no comma is needed.

```
MyClass< decltype(std::declval<Ts>()()) ... > d;
```